# Using BurpSuite on third-party iOS Apps using ATS

Tags: ios, mobile, mitmproxy, burp

I've been doing some mobile pentesting for a client and wanted to get stuck into some Network Analysis. I have jailbroken an iPhone & disabled SSL pinning, as well as configured Burp to intercept HTTP requests through Safari.
However, BurpSuite fails to intercept any traffic on the third-party app. After reviewing some scans, I can see the App uses ATS which I presume is my hindrance.

So my question is: How can I intercept traffic on Applications using ATS if it is at all possible?

Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: So the app has pinned certificates in it's ATS configuration? Have you tried what happens if you disable certificate pinning via Frida+Objection?

Comment: I've disabled SSL pinning with SSLKillSwitch, I figured that would comprehensively disable certificate pinning throughout the device. Do you think disabling it with Frida+Objection would retrieve different results?

Comment: The ATS config for pining via `NSPinnedCAIdentities` was introduced in iOS14, SSLKillSwitch seems to be older than iOS14 so I would assume that it does not yet support overriding ATS based certificate pinning. But I don't know where and how ATS cert pinning is implemented.

Comment: This is useful input, thank you. I also am not sure where ATS cert pinning is implemented. I know it is in use because the MobSF scan says so, however, there's no mention of it in the info.plist file. I'll attempt another method of disabling SSL pinning.